# Insert widgets after theme installation

Tags: widgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install widget on plugin activation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/install-widget-on-plugin-activation)
>   [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars)

I'm creating a theme and after the installation it is need put the widgets. Exists any way to setup some widgets automatically? Some specific function to make it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22085/install-widget-on-plugin-activation/22090#22090)