# Adding a widget programmatically

Tags: plugins, widgets, sidebar

I want to add widgets to my wordpress site programmatically. I tried the following code from the [codex docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget):

```
class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {

    function MyNewWidget() {
        // Instantiate the parent object
        parent::__construct( false, 'My New Widget Title' );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // Widget output
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // Save widget options
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        // Output admin widget options form
    }
}

function myplugin_register_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'MyNewWidget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'myplugin_register_widgets' );
```

But doesn't seem to work. I even tried the code from the question [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars) but to no avail. Please tell me if I am missing out something.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is just like prototype, it doesn't display anything.
That's why your are not seeing anything in dashboard.

```
/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            esc_html__( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

} // class Foo_Widget

// register Foo_Widget widget
function register_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );
```

I just copied this code from wordpress.org but you can modify it to your need
.Reply if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

here is an example that should work with the latest version of wordpress:

```
 class MyNewWidget extends WP_Widget {
        function MyNewWidget() {
            parent::WP_Widget(false, 'My New Widget');
        }
        function form($instance) {
            // outputs the options form on admin
        }
        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            // processes widget options to be saved
            return $new_instance;
        }
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            echo('<span>this is my widget</span>');
        }
    }
    register_widget('MyNewWidget');
```