# Where is the content of widgets stored in mysql table

Tags: widgets, sidebar, mysql

I have the cPanel access to a website but no wordpress login info. So I wants to change a widget content in the website.

How can I change it through phpmyadmin. Where are that widgets sidebar data actually stored? Is it inside `wp-options` table?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Widget options are stored in the `options` table under `'sidebars_widgets'` as a serialized array. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51086/73) for a longer explanation.

[image]

Changing the field per PHPMyAdmin is not recommended, use PHP, `get_option()` and `update_option()` instead, WordPress will take care for correct serialization then.

Comment: Impressive! I don't know how to update the values using that function. Anyway I solved my problem by creating another user through phpmyadmin. Thank You.