# Change Widgets Order In Plugin - Get Array Of Sidebar Widgets

Tags: widgets, array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars)

i create front-site drag and drop layout manager.
I need to change widget order, when user drag widget A over widget B, but how wordpress save widgets order?

I think, that i must **get array of widgets**, that's applying to current sidebar. How can i do this?