# What is this instance variable doing in the Widgets class

Tags: widgets

The lack of documentation for the WP_Widget class is driving me mad. Here is what I have salvaged off the codex:

```
    public function form($instance){
        ?>

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: 
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" />
        </label>

        <?php
    }
```

What is this `$instance` variable? The docs say it is `The settings for the particular instance of the widget`. But then why isnt it just another property of `$this`. Why does `$this->get_field_name('title')` seem to know something about a title and suddenly when we want the goddamn title I have to start going into this `instance` variable. What am I missing here.

Can you explain me where the `$title` is held, what the hell the `$instance` is different from `$this` and why we are using the title to get the field name?

Thanks loads!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$instance` holds the data stored for this widget instance as an array. You could use the same widget multiple times, and each would get different data.

`get_field_name()` and `get_field_id()` returns name/id attributes for that widget. They are unique for each widget, but do not depend on the data. That’s why they do not have to know anything about the `$instance`:

```
function get_field_name($field_name) {
    return 'widget-' . $this->id_base . '[' . $this->number . '][' . $field_name . ']';
}
```

Comment: when you say `They are unique for each widget` do you mean even if they are the same widget but because they are used multiple times they are unique?

Comment: Yes, the number is always unique. Read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51086/73) to understand how WordPress creates widget instances.