# How to hook into unregistering a widget instance?

Tags: filters, widgets, hooks

I would like to hook into a widget instance after it is removed from a sidebar panel on the Appearances -> Widgets admin page.

So if the instance was an active widget and then removed, I would like to hook into that instance before it is removed.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be done. Ultimately, adding and removing a widget to/from a sidebar means updating an option in the database with a call like this:

```
update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', array( ... ) )
```

If you look at the code of [`update_option`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/option.php#L253) you see that there is a filter called just before the actual update. So if you want to do something before a widget is removed you can hook into:

```
add_filter ('pre_update_option_sidebars_widgets','wpse71075_pre_remove_widget',10,3);
```

At this point you only know that the list of active widgets is going to change, not whether it is addition or a removal. However, you do have `$value` and `$old_value` of the option, which you can compare inside your filter function (an `array_search` for a widget's label might be enough).

Read the [answer to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars/51086#51086) to learn about the structure of the `sidebars_widgets` option. It depends on your goal what you actually want to detect and do.