# Adding custom menu widget to sidebar programatically

Tags: menus, widgets, xml-rpc

I am trying to add custom menu widget to the sidebar. I am not working on wordpress directly, but I am using an xml-rpc calls to manage worpdress site (it is possible via http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/ plugin). I am trying to achieve this using **wp_set_sidebars_widgets** function (I think its a proper way). First I am calling **wp_get_sidebars_widgets** to receive list of active sidebars and widgets. It gives me an array like that:

> Array ( [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array ( [0] => archives-2 [1] =>
>   meta-2 [2] => search-2 [3] => categories-2 [4] => recent-posts-2 [5]
>   => recent-comments-2 [6] => nav_menu-2 [7] => nav_menu-3 [8] => nav_menu-4 ) **[sidebar-1] => Array ( )** [footer-1] => Array ( )
>   [footer-2] => Array ( ) [footer-3] => Array ( ) )

Now I am adding nav_menu-2 value to sidebar-1, so array looks like:

> Array ( [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array ( [0] => archives-2 [1] =>
>   meta-2 [2] => search-2 [3] => categories-2 [4] => recent-posts-2 [5]
>   => recent-comments-2 [6] => nav_menu-2 [7] => nav_menu-3 [8] => nav_menu-4 ) **[sidebar-1] => Array ( [0] => nav_menu-2 )** [footer-1] =>
>   Array ( ) [footer-2] => Array ( ) [footer-3] => Array ( ) )

Now Im sending this array with **wp_set_sidebars_widgets** and problem is, that on wordpress Ive got 8 inactive sidebars instead of custom menu in sidebar-1. Calling **wp_get_sidebars_widgets** gives me now an array:

> Array ( [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array ( [0] => archives-2 [1] =>
>   meta-2 [2] => search-2 [3] => categories-2 [4] => recent-posts-2 [5]
>   => recent-comments-2 [6] => nav_menu-2 [7] => nav_menu-3 [8] => nav_menu-4 ) [1] => meta-2 [2] => search-2 [3] => categories-2 [4] =>
>   recent-posts-2 [5] => recent-comments-2 [6] => nav_menu-2 [7] =>
>   nav_menu-3 [8] => nav_menu-4 )

Its  What Im doing wrong? Maybe someone knows another way to add custom menu to sidebar?

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars/51086#51086)?

Comment: Thank you toscho. I have read that answer before, but i didnt noticed on that function **update_option("sidebars_widgets",$active_widgets)**. This is answer for my question. If You want to turn on widget in your sidebar, you just have to make some code like this: '$active_widget = get_option("sidebars_widgets"); $active_widget["sidebar-1"][] = "nav_menu-2"; update_option("sidebars_widgets",$active_widgets);' Thank you toscho again.