# Adding custom widgets to theme sidebar on activation

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I have a custom widget in my theme with the id of "widget_my_box_menu" and I'm trying to add that widget to my theme's main sidebar on theme activation. The main sidebar's id is "home-sidebar-widget"

When I activate the theme, the widget_my_box_menu is added to the "Inactive Widgets" collection instead of the "home-sidebar-widget"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
function my_default_theme_widgets ($old_theme, $WP_theme = null) {
            $new_active_widgets = array (
                'home-sidebar-widget' => array (
                        'widget_my_box_menu',
                ),
        );

        // save new widgets to DB
        update_option('sidebars_widgets', $new_active_widgets);

        //widget title
        update_option( 'widget_my_box_menu', array( 'title' => 'Recent Articles' ));

}
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_default_theme_widgets', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Have you read [this topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars)?

Comment: Yes, but I got a bit lost in the details of the example