# How to add a text widget during theme activation

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I'm trying to add a text widget with the title and text set, to two custom sidebars in my custom theme.  But, I can't find a clear walkthrough of how to do it.  I've seen bits of code here and there, but nothing that clearly walks through the process of programatically adding the text widget to a sidebar.

I've seen [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars) but it revolves around a custom widget which is not what I'm trying to do.

Edit:
I have two sidebars - footer-left and footer-right.  Here's what I have tried but it has not worked.  So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', 
        array ( 
        'footer-left' => array ( 0 => array( 'title' => 'Test1', 'text' => 'Test 1 Test')), 
        'footer-right' => array ( 0 => array( 'title' => 'Test2', 'text' => 'Test 2 Test')), 
        ) );
```

Comment: The code in that linked question will work if you think it through. All of the pieces are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, except each widget's settings are stored separately from the `sidebars_widgets` option, which just stores widget "instances".

Try out the following function - you'll still need to use `register_sidebar`, but it eases the pain for then pre-registering widgets *on those sidebars*.  What it also does is ensure that any existing widgets & their settings aren't lost in the process.

```
/**
 * Pre-configure and save a widget, designed for plugin and theme activation.
 * 
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/138242/1685
 *
 * @param   string  $sidebar    The database name of the sidebar to add the widget to.
 * @param   string  $name       The database name of the widget.
 * @param   mixed   $args       The widget arguments (optional).
 */
function wpse_138242_pre_set_widget( $sidebar, $name, $args = array() ) {
    if ( ! $sidebars = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' ) )
        $sidebars = array();

    // Create the sidebar if it doesn't exist.
    if ( ! isset( $sidebars[ $sidebar ] ) )
        $sidebars[ $sidebar ] = array();

    // Check for existing saved widgets.
    if ( $widget_opts = get_option( "widget_$name" ) ) {
        // Get next insert id.
        ksort( $widget_opts );
        end( $widget_opts );
        $insert_id = key( $widget_opts );
    } else {
        // None existing, start fresh.
        $widget_opts = array( '_multiwidget' => 1 );
        $insert_id = 0;
    }

    // Add our settings to the stack.
    $widget_opts[ ++$insert_id ] = $args;
    // Add our widget!
    $sidebars[ $sidebar ][] = "$name-$insert_id";

    update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebars );
    update_option( "widget_$name", $widget_opts );
}
```

In your case:

```
wpse_138242_pre_set_widget( 'footer-left', 'text',
    array(
        'title' => 'Test1',
        'text' => 'Test 1 Test',
        'filter' => false,
    )
);

wpse_138242_pre_set_widget( 'footer-right', 'text',
    array(
        'title' => 'Test2',
        'text' => 'Test 2 Test',
        'filter' => false,
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works, but something isn't working right with the code that is supposed to see if the widget already exists.  I have this firing in my widgets_init() hook and every time I go into the theme options area it re-adds the widgets.  Actually, it appears to be doubling them.  So first there were two, then four, then 8, etc.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  I just tried it again and it is only adding one at a time rather than doubling it.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this is designed for theme & plugin *activation* - if you fire it on `widgets_init` of course it'll keep adding them!

Comment: For actual moment this function do not update `sidebars_widgets` option in database at all. After installing and activation of theme, in database option `sidebars_widgets` have all of my registered sidebars from functions.php, but then, when i execute this function in my script, database entry `sidebars_widgets` won't to be updated. There is no problem with update `widget_$name` option. Options from `$args` are stored there but I noticed that this function do not add for ex. `i:2;a:4:` but only `a:4`. I think this funciton should be corrected somehow.