# How to create a live demo page for a theme?

Tags: themes

How can you create a live demo page for a theme ?

something like a wordpress theme showcase, allowing customers to preview a specific theme live before they decide to purchase.

I have seen this on studiopress for example or any major theme seller.

Example.com - main website

Example.com/theme1/ - displays a demo of a certain theme

example.com/theme2/ - another theme, ETC

Can this be done with a plugin? Or do you have a better idea perhaps multisite?

Thank you

Comment: Create a sub-domain ( `demo.site.com` ) and supposing you have `theme 1`, install WP at `/theme1` ( `demo.site.com/theme1` ) and go to themes and activate `theme1`.. just a thought,

Comment: Yes, but in order to be able to have theme2 , theme 3, theme x, I should have multisite enabled. Right?

Comment: Yes, either multi-site or doing multiple WordPress installations.

Comment: What about something like: https://github.com/OriginalEXE/Switcheroo - I never tried though.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it in a plugin:

1. Install WordPress as a multisite with subdomains.
2. Use the main site for the theme shop, install Easy Digital Downloads or another shop plugin. Create a product for each theme, make sure the slug matches the theme directory name.
3. Upload your themes.
4. Write an empty function `wp_install_defaults()` to prevent the default content in new sites.
5. Add the test data from [wptest.io](http://wptest.io/) to your plugin. They are better than the WordPress theme test data.
6. Hook into `wpmu_new_blog` and check if the site slug matches an existing theme. Then:

   - Install the test data.
   - Set the option `blog_public` to `FALSE` to prevent search engines from indexing your test data.
   - Create or update a site option with an array containing the site ID, the theme slug and the visible theme name that you get from the `style.css`.
   - Activate the matching theme.
   - Create a sticky post from the content of the `style.css` and add a *Buy now!* link that goes to the product on the main site with a matching slug.
7. Force the admin bar to be visible on all sites, even when the user is not logged in. Add a menu that is fed from the site option and build a list of all theme preview sites. You can also [use a widget](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51086/73) for that.
8. Filter the product page on the main site and add a link to the demo site with the information from the site option.

There are probably many details that I missed here, but as a basic concept, this should work fine.

Comment: This seems good. I will accept it as an answer. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Edit. I will still wait for answers that not require coding myself. Perhaps an already build plugin. Or another solution ofc