# Adding widgets programatically: how to avoid collisions?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I am developing a theme, and I'm trying to add widgets programatically to its sidebar. I read this excellent answer:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51086/14225

But there's one thing I'm not clear on: where do you get the number you append to the widgets? (`search-2`, `archives-3`, etc.). For example, the default widgets on a fresh WP installed are initialized thus:

```
update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', array ( 'wp_inactive_widgets' => array (), 'sidebar-1' => array ( 0 => 'search-2', 1 => 'recent-posts-2', 2 => 'recent-comments-2', 3 => 'archives-2', 4 => 'categories-2', 5 => 'meta-2', ), 'array_version' => 3 ) );
```

Why `search-2` and not `search-1`, for example? OTOH, the linked answer above just uses a `$counter` variable to give each widget in a sidebar a different number, starting with 1.

I realize all this is to avoid collisions between different instances of the same widget. What I don't understand is at which level one is supposed to avoid them: between different widgets in the same sidebar? Different instances of the same widget, added to different themes? Different instances of the same widget in the same theme, but in different sidebars? What's the best practice when generating numbers to avoid collisions?

Comment: With widgets added on the configuration panel, the widget identifier name is used by WordPress as the id property in the resulting HTML. That makes me think you should, at least, avoid having two widgets with the same ID in the same page.

Comment: Even if they have different names? The default widgets are all added as `search-2`, `recent-comments-2`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code that WordPress uses to register widgets [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/widgets.php#L0), there's a $number parameter defined, in line 242, as:

> The unique order number of this widget instance compared to other instances of the same class.

The function `_set($number)` stores this ID number attached to the base identifier string of the widget.

Then, the function `get_settings` retrieves all configuration options for all the instances of the widget, in all sidebars. And when they are registered is when this `$number` part of the full widget ID is generated:

```
 public function _register() {
                $settings = $this->get_settings();
                $empty = true;

                if ( is_array($settings) ) {
                        foreach ( array_keys($settings) as $number ) {
                                if ( is_numeric($number) ) {
                                        $this->_set($number);
                                        $this->_register_one($number);
                                        $empty = false;
                                }
                        }
                }
[...]
```

In the `register_one` function, we find this:

> integer $number Optional. The unique order number of this widget instance
>                                 compared to other instances of the same class.

So, the combination of the ID `$number` with the `$id_base` name has to be unique for all the instances of your widget, in any sidebar.