# Add default widgets to footer

Tags: widgets, footer

How can I add default widgets to footer. I want 4 default widgets appear in footer of my custom theme after installation

```
<footer>

if(is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area'  )
&& is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' )
&& is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area'  )
&& is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' )) { ?>

<aside class="fatfooter" role="complementary">
<div class="first quarter left widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
</div><!-- .first .widget-area -->

<div class="second quarter widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'second-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
</div><!-- .second .widget-area -->

<div class="third quarter widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'third-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
</div><!-- .third .widget-area -->

<div class="fourth quarter right widget-area">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'fourth-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
</div><!-- .fourth .widget-area -->
</aside><!-- #fatfooter --> 

<?php } ?>

</footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically add widgets to sidebars](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars)